# how can I use a variable from my php part of the code in the script part?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

Here is the php part:

```
include realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Classes/Controllers/ReportController.php');
global $scheduleResult = ReportController::getVacRep();

$count = 0;
$resultData['0','0','0','0','0','0','0'];

foreach ($scheduleResult as $rowResult) {
    $resultData[count] = $rowResult[vaccValue];
    $count++;
}
```

I need to use the  $result Data array in this code block, Given that this part of the code is javascript between `<script> </script>`

```
var barChartData = {
    labels : ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],
    datasets : [
        {
            highlightFill: "#45668e",
            highlightStroke: "#45668e",
            fillColor : "#1ABC9C",
            strokeColor : "#1ABC9C",
            data : [90,90,90,90,90,90,90]
        }
]};
```

I need to use the array in this part in the script code `data : [90,90,90,90,90,90,90]` where in the place of each number here (the 90's) I need to put the values stored in the array but I am not sure how I can use the array from the php in the script code. I tried to google it but I did not understand how to do it or if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your javascript is within the php file, just put `<?php echo $data; ?>` where you need the data, else you can put a `<script>` tag in your php page, (the HTML) before your external script tag, and define a global javascript variable in there, so that you can use the data in the external script file.

```
data : [
  <?php echo $resultData[0]; ?>,
  <?php echo $resultData[1]; ?>,
  <?php echo $resultData[2]; ?>
]
```

Comment: okay I am still getting an error so I excuse me for my question I am still a beginner, if the array is declared and initialised in a block of <?php ?> and then I am using it in a different block of php but they are both in the same file, will it still be visible and usable in both php blocks?

Comment: Yes it is available in the same file. see my edit, if the php and js codes you have in your question are in the same file, you can do this

Comment: or simply: `data: <?php echo json_encode($data);?>`.